# An example real life use for a tree data structure in C++?

Tags: c++, c

When I was in school, we had an assignment of implementing a 2-3 tree. I did so and built the following 2-3 tree https://github.com/awm086/2-3-tree/blob/master/2_3_tree.cpp.

Now that I am looking back and trying to refresh my c++ knowledge, I could not help but wonder, how could I use this data structure in a real life example. I would like to be able to write a program that could utilize this data structure. So I guess I am asking for a real life example (simple enough that I can implement) that uses a tree data structure?

Comment: What is the definition of a 2-3 tree? Your code is missing the most important part: the documentation of what the type does.

Comment: a simple real life problem: a dictionary

Comment: Try writing a spellchecker.  Then try writing an application that does word completion as you type.  For example, as you type "comp" your program would suggest some possible completions:  "complete", "computer", "comprehend", etc.

Comment: @David Rodríguez, I am asking for a real life example (simple enough that I can implement) that uses a tree data structure (any tree)? Something that could be implemented in a company or so.

Comment: thank you @JohnDibling  I will look at examples see how this could be implemented using a tree.

Comment: @Ali: *Any tree*? An expression evaluator can be implemented as a tree where each operator is a node and the operands are the children nodes, but my impression is that a 2-3 tree is a *balanced binary tree* of sorts, and that cannot be used in an expression evaluator as balancing the tree would change the expression. Do you realize how the definition of what your tree is **does matter**?

Answer (score 2):

Trees are used in associative containers like [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/), for example, because they give a very fast lookup, insertion and deletion.

Comment: std::map normally is a red black tree.

Comment: The C++ standard does not state that a std::map must be implemented using red-black trees, it is just that this is a common way of implementing them. There are several types of tree data structures that are balanced (optimal search depth) and have fast insertion/deletion: red-black trees are one; 2-3 trees are another.

Answer (score 2):

From the Wikipedia page for 2-3 Trees,

> 2-3 trees are an isometry of AA trees, meaning that they are equivalent data structures. In other words, for every 2-3 tree, there exists at least one AA tree with data elements in the same order.

and (from AA Trees)

> An AA tree in computer science is a form of balanced tree used for storing and retrieving ordered data efficiently.

and finally,

> The performance of an AA tree is equivalent to the performance of a red-black tree. While an AA tree makes more rotations than a red-black tree, the simpler algorithms tend to be faster, and all of this balances out to result in similar performance. A red-black tree is more consistent in its performance than an AA tree, but an AA tree tends to be flatter, which results in slightly faster search times.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean why use a tree - or why a 2-3 tree?

Trees let you store an ordered set of data without (much) re-sorting when you add new data

2-3 trees are optomised so that they don't become unbalanced

Comment: I know what the tree is and how it works. What I need to enhance my understanding, is a real life use case of a tree (any tree) that I could implement myself. Examples such  as the ones mentioned in the comments above. I am not sure if I should edit my question to better explain what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The tree data structure is hugely used in many places you can do something as follows.

- `Data base designing`

you can create your own database just to store the data basing upon some value suppose a BST(binary search tree) then you can chose value that will be smaller and bigger and basing upon these value you can store the data in the tree nodes.

- `Creating file system`

This is the area where tree are used hugely ,so you can try these.